# The variable is assignd but never use even if it is ? Confusing

Tags: c#

Hello i am quite a noob at c# and i don't understand why its saying that the variable is never used even tho i am using it and it is very clear.

Does it not reac the if statment ?

```
  public void SetStellplatz(Fahrzeuge Anmeldung)
    {
        bool is_pkw = false;
        bool is_motorrad = false;
        bool is_lkw = false;
        int stellplatznummer; 

        if(Anmeldung is PKW)
        {
            is_pkw = true;
            stellplatznummer = GetStellplatz(1, 199);

        } else if(Anmeldung is Motorrad)
        {
            is_motorrad = true;
            stellplatznummer = GetStellplatz(200, 399);
        } else if (Anmeldung is LKW)
        {
            is_lkw = true;
            stellplatznummer = GetStellplatz(400, 599);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Assigned != Used.

Comment: I dont undestand. I am using the variable ? No ?

Comment: **Which** variable are you referring to?

Comment: ok, so is_motorrad = true.  Who cares?  You never use it anywhere.  Why does it matter if it's true?

Comment: @Amy My mistakes, i am reffering to the bools.

Comment: My guess is you have `bool is_motorrad` somewhere else in your code.  These would be different variables in different scopes.

Comment: All the variables declared in method are not getting used anywhere (apart from assignment).  Why do you need reference to some data if you are not going to use it ?

Answer (score 1):

Your if statement lacks an else clause, so the variable `stellplatznummer` is not guaranteed to be assigned in all cases. You can fix it by including an else statement that sets the value of the variable, or by initializing the variable to a default value when you define it.

Comment: This is technically true, but all four of the local variables get set and immediately thrown away. It seems likely he's missing the "bigger picture".

Answer (score 0):

Your method isn't doing anything as all of your variables have local scope. Your method is equivalent to:

```
public void SetStellplatz(Fahrzeuge Anmeldung)
{
    if (Anmeldung is PKW)
        GetStellplatz(1, 199);
    else if (Anmeldung is Motorrad)
        GetStellplatz(200, 399);
    else if (Anmeldung is LKW)
        GetStellplatz(400, 599);
}
```

It seems likely some of those variables should be class fields or possibly properties.

```
// Private Field
private bool is_pkw = false;

// Public Property
public bool is_motorrad { get; set; } = false;

public void SetStellplatz(Fahrzeuge Anmeldung)
{
    // if some condition
    is_pkw = true;

    // if some other condition
    is_motorrad = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You create the variable stellplatznummer in that method, when the method finish the variable is destroyed because is only for that method and you never return it.

Try to say for what do you want to use that method.

```
    public int stellplatznummer; 
    public bool is_pkw = false;
    public bool is_motorrad = false;
    public bool is_lkw = false;

     public void SetStellplatz(Fahrzeuge Anmeldung)
    {



        if(Anmeldung is PKW)
        {
            is_pkw = true;
            stellplatznummer = GetStellplatz(1, 199);

        } else if(Anmeldung is Motorrad)
        {
            is_motorrad = true;
            stellplatznummer = GetStellplatz(200, 399);
        } else if (Anmeldung is LKW)
        {
            is_lkw = true;
            stellplatznummer = GetStellplatz(400, 599);
        }
    }
```

if the method SetStellplatz set stellplatznummer with the number, where do you want to use it. How you will acces to this number. And please give as the code of Anmeldung may be help.

Beside that I don't udnerstand your language but it's possible that you will not need to do a method that SetStellplatz.